# Move bin folder of MVC C# project

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller

I want to know if it is possible to move the default bin folder of MVC project. As default location is in `RootProjectPath/bin`, is it possible to move this bin folder out of the project path and remove the default bin folder?

Answer (score 4):

Properties-> Build-> OutputPath - you can set there any other name of folder

Comment: Yes but only on the ProjectPath/bin/otherPath.... .My question is if it is possible to create the bin folder out of the default path ProjectPath/bin to C:\MyBin\bin for example.

Comment: Sure you can move bin folder anywhere where you want/ It contains all libraries that you app need. When you work with MVC the best choice is not to move bin folder, but publish it on specified IIS path.